# Trying to have multiple people connected to a Socket in python

Tags: python, sockets

Im trying to have multiple clients be able to connect to a server however when a second user connects it kicks the other client off the server as you cant have 2 clients connected to a socket and i was wondering if there was anything around this.

**server.py**

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = '10.41.13.228'
    port = 5000


    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))

    s.listen(1)


    name = input("Please Enter your name - ")
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
        data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print(data)
    c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

**Client.py**

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = '10.41.13.228'
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))


   name = input("Please enter your name - ")
   message = input("-> ")
   while True:
        while message != 'q':
            ToSend = (str(name) + " - " + str(message))
            s.sendall(ToSend.encode('utf-8'))
            message = input("-> ")
        s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem i noticed in your code is `s.listen` method. Where you are listening to only one client connection. You could increase the amount to have more clients connected to the server.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example):

> Note that a server must perform the sequence socket(), bind(), listen(), accept() (possibly repeating the accept() to service more than one client), while a client only needs the sequence socket(), connect(). Also note that the server does not sendall()/recv() on the socket it is listening on but on the new socket returned by accept().

Therefore, there are two missing parts in your code.

1. As already commented, your [listen()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen) method should take a 2 as argument (as you intend to have 2 clients).
2. You should call [accept()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) twice. Remember to keep in mind the comment of the example. Quoting again:

   > note that the server does not sendall()/recv() on the socket it is
   >   listening on but on the new socket returned by accept()

Out of topic. It is indeed a good practice to have a keyword such as 'exit' to break from the loop of your server once recieved.